# 'MainActivity' does not contain a definition for 'SetVolumeControl'

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, volume

I am trying to make phone's volume buttons to automatically change media volume instead of ringtone volume while in my app. I found that you should put this line `this.SetVolumeControlStream(Android.Media.Stream.Music);`
I am trying to do that in OnCreate method but it says that MainActivity does not contain a definition for SetVolumeControlStream and no extension method. I realise that I am probably writing this line in the wrong place, any suggestions how to make this line work in my app?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Content.PM;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Support.V7.App;
using Android.Widget;
using foosballv2s.Source.Activities.Adapters;
using foosballv2s.Source.Activities.Helpers;
using foosballv2s.Source.Entities;
using foosballv2s.Source.Services.FileIO;
using foosballv2s.Source.Services.FoosballWebService.Repository;
using Java.Interop;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using View = Android.Views.View;
using Android.Media;

namespace foosballv2s.Source.Activities
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Main activity for choosing the teams for the game
    /// </summary>
    [Activity(
        ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.Orientation,
        ScreenOrientation = ScreenOrientation.Portrait
        )]
    public class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity
    {
        private AutoCompleteTextView firstTeamTextView, secondTeamTextView;
        private IO instance = new IO();
        private Game game;
        private TeamRepository teamRepository;


        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            AudioManager audio = (AudioManager)GetSystemService(Context.AudioService);
            int currentVolume = audio.GetStreamVolume(Android.Media.Stream.Music);
            this.SetVolumeControlStream(Android.Media.Stream.Music);
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

            global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, savedInstanceState);

            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

            game = DependencyService.Get<Game>();
            teamRepository = DependencyService.Get<TeamRepository>();

            firstTeamTextView = (AutoCompleteTextView)FindViewById<AutoCompleteTextView>(Resource.Id.team1Name);
            secondTeamTextView = (AutoCompleteTextView)FindViewById<AutoCompleteTextView>(Resource.Id.team2Name);

            firstTeamTextView.ItemClick += AutoCompleteTextView_ItemClicked;
            secondTeamTextView.ItemClick += AutoCompleteTextView_ItemClicked;

            var btnP = FindViewById<Android.Widget.Button>(Resource.Id.prev);
            btnP.Click += BtnPrev_Click;

            //Window.SetBackgroundDrawable(Android.Resource.Id.);
            NavigationHelper.SetupNavigationListener(this);
            NavigationHelper.SetActionBarNavigationText(this, Resource.String.app_name);
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in Xamarin, Java Set* and Get* Methods are typically mapped to C# properties.  So `SetVolumeControlStream()` becomes `VolumeControlStream` with a getter and setter instead.

this is documented in the [API](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/property/Android.App.Dialog.VolumeControlStream/) guide

```
[get: Android.Runtime.Register("getVolumeControlStream", "()I", "GetGetVolumeControlStreamHandler")]
[set: Android.Runtime.Register("setVolumeControlStream", "(I)V", "GetSetVolumeControlStream_IHandler")]
public Stream VolumeControlStream { get; set; }
```

Comment: I have seen that, but didn't get what it meant. Trying this one more time I understood and changed 'this.SetVolumeControlStream(Android.Media.Stream.Music);' to 'VolumeControlStream = Android.Media.Stream.Music;' 
It works now, thank you!